# How can I fix a bootstrap 5 navbar constantly being sticky

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried almost everything, tried to set the position to fixed, navbar-fixed-top, and fixed-top but the goddamn navbar is still sticky.
I am redoing someones work so idk how the thing was constructed, there is no css making the position sticky aswell. I also checked multiple stack overflow posts which weren't fixing my problem :(

Using bootstrap 5.0.0-beta2

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light navbar-expand-md navigation-clean-button" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="assets/img/logo.png?h=ab49f36f40cf5da832aa34d1c073cb5f"></a><button data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-target="#navcol-1"><span class="visually-hidden">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button></div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-right me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="https://app.gitbook.com/@nmms/s/nmms-mm-docs/" style="color: white;">Documentation</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="https://discord.gg/nmms" style="color: white;">Discord</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="color:white;">
                          Aplications
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="margin-top:20px;">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfipqGDH-meNOEHj5UOiHTKLgOnstOu0mlu9eEm0melCSRxTw/viewform?usp=pp_url" style="color:white;">Mod application</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc3WJO1W43CTi83xvm2mG34DVR9Of9Q0QSJ8YiQIL3rtk6brQ/viewform?usp=pp_url" style="color:white;">Ban appeal</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white;">Boost Rewards</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="https://app.gitbook.com/@nmms/s/nmms-mm-docs/~/drafts/-MkE8So6PSq6YGBf9nKA/tos-for-use">TOS</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"></li>
                </ul><!-- Start: Actions -->
                <p class="navbar-text actions" style="/*float: right;*/"> </p><!-- End: Actions -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Any help with be appreciated :)

Comment: Remove the `fixed-top` class from the `<nav>` element - the bootstrap documentation explains this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement

Comment: Add your custom style on page with nav-rules from my pen [header and footer sticky](https://codepen.io/zazaulola/pen/zYzbEqG)